# How do I import normal enum in maven project?

Tags: java, maven, enums

I'm porting a project to Maven. It seems that I'm almost done, though there's still a strange problem. I have an enum:

```
package cz.autoclient.settings;

public enum Setnames {
  SETTING1("s1", false),
  SETTING2("s2", 666),
  ;

  public final String name;
  public final Object def;
  Setnames(String n, Object d) {
    name = n;
    def = d;    
  }
}
```

I use this particular `enum` to avoid re-creation of `String` whenever some setting is loaded from the database. And to store default values.

In my old project, this was valid:

```
import cz.autoclient.settings.Setnames;
```

In Maven, there's a problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cz/autoclient/settings/Setnames
    at cz.autoclient.Gui.createTabs(Gui.java:326)
    at cz.autoclient.Gui.initComponents(Gui.java:165)
    at cz.autoclient.Gui.<init>(Gui.java:58)
    at cz.autoclient.Main.startGUI(Main.java:71)
    at cz.autoclient.Main.<init>(Main.java:32)
    at cz.autoclient.Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cz.autoclient.settings.Setnames
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

`Gui.java:326` is the line where I first use `Setnames`. I've been googling and what I got that you've got to use `$` when naming enums *somehow*.

But I've no idea where should I put that `$` in my case - other people allways had this problem when `enum` was hidden within a class.

Here's what it looks like in my IDE:

[image: image description]

Here's the project `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


  <groupId>cz.autoclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>autoclient</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <src.dir>src/</src.dir>
    <test.dir>test/</test.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${test.dir}</testSourceDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>${src.dir}</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <name>Auto Client</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
      <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the command line NetBeans is using to compile the project:

> `cd C:\MYSELF\programing\java\AutoCall\AutoClient; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_31" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Users\\Jakub\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\7.4\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath cz.autoclient.Main\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_31\\bin\\java.exe\" -DnetbeansProjectMappings= -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Users\\Jakub\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\7.4\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""`

Comment: Where is this enum defined and how to try add the maven dependency?

Comment: It's in my project, why should I add dependency? And of course, it's in `cz.autoclient.settings`, which means directory `\cz\autoclient\settings\Setnames.java`.

Comment: Please show your full pom files which you use? which Maven version do you use? And how you call Maven?

Comment: I can't answer these questions. I just created new Maven project in netbeans. It must do this to everyone...

Comment: Post the POM. What Java version are you specifying with? I wonder whether your project is stuck on 1.4.

Comment: With "POM" they mean the file "pom.xml" that should have been created when you created the maven project in Netbeans. This xml file is your new project file that contains all the information about it.

Comment: I added this file, but I see nothing relevant in it. Please review it and tell me which part is related to `enum`s - otherwise I might remove it as it's making the question too long. I think I use Java 8 - I get no errors for `default` functions in interfaces.

Comment: Also I hate it when people downvote questions just because they don't know the answer. I provided all info I could think of. It's not my fault that the problem is complicated - that doesn't make it bad question.

Comment: What command are you using to compile and execute your project? What are you doing that leads up to the error?

Comment: I really just normally `import` `enum` using the statement described in my question. I'll try to find out the command line - but again, it must be generated by NetBeans. And Netbeans should obey the `pom.xml` above. *Edit: I added the command line*.

Comment: Source/target="8" seems strange, usually I see "1.8".

Comment: Seems both options are equal - changing this had no effect, positive or negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was some kind of glitch in the project. I have no idea how it happened.

Refactoring the packages with problematic classes fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You created a maven project and moved your class from `cz.autoclient.settings.Setnames` to `cz.autoclient.PVP_net.Setnames`. Now you're getting an `NoClassDefFoundError` which means that java simply can't find your class. Why? Because it's moved to another place, but this has nothing to do with maven it has just happened after creating a maven project.

Please check your whole project for imports like:

```
import cz.autoclient.settings.Setnames;
```

an replace them by something like:

```
import cz.autoclient.PVP_net.Setnames;
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Sorry, the whole `.settings.` things is a confusion. Because of search engines, I originally didn't want to expose `PVP_net` here. It's a trademark of some company.

Comment: On that note it should be also remembered that NetBeans do NOT report any problems with finding classes. The project structure is correct.